# Jquery - please wait with delete confirmation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have added a please wait animated gif to server calls on a test page and it works fine on its own. The code to call the animated please wait gif is:

```
onclick="ShowProgressAnimation();"
```

The issue I have is that on a delete button I have a pop up confirmation message (the confirmation pop up has the standard OK CANCEL buttons) that I want to add the animated please wait gif to.

Adding the two scripts together causes two faults:

Fault 1 is that when I select the OK button, the animated please wait gif stops spinning (the related record is deleted); and

Fault 2 is that when I click the CANCEL button the please wait animated gif sits and spins and does not stop (presumably because there is no server call when I select the CANCEL button to stop the animated gif spinning).

Here is my code to call both the please wait animated gif and the confirmation pop up:

```
onclick="ShowProgressAnimation();return confirmDelete();"
```

Here is the confirmation pop up script:

```
function confirmDelete() {
    confirm("Are you certain you want to DELETE this record?");}
```

**How do I combine both scripts so that when I select the CANCEL button of the confirmation popup the please wait animated gif is cancelled AND when I select the OK button on the confirmation pop up the please wait animated gif continues to spin?**

Comment: It would be great if u create a jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve this by the following code:

```
onclick="if(confirmDelete())showProgressAnimation();else return false;"
```

This way the show progress will be called only if the user selects the OK dialogue button. If the user selects the CANCEL dialogue button the user is returned to the page without deleting the record.

I hope this helps someone.